# unable to set session in codeigniter REST API

Tags: rest, codeigniter

i am trying to get a varibale from one function to another function using rest api.here is my code.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', $authUser['id']);

        $this->session->userdata('some_name');
```

Comment: Kindly post what error you are getting.

Comment: nothing showing.the form is not submiting

Comment: Kindly post some of your more relevant code so that we can understand better and help you.

Comment: public function clinic_post()

{


$area=$this->post('area');

$locality=$this->post('locality');


 $add_image=array(
                    'area'=>$area,
                     'locality'=>$locality,

                      'doctor_id' =>$this->session->set_userdata('some_name'));
                      
            $this->load->model('ApiModel');
            $this->ApiModel->clinic_insert($add_image);




           
   
}

Answer (score 0):

```
public function clinic_post() { 
 $area      = $this->post('area'); 
 $locality  = $this->post('locality'); 
 $add_image     = array( 
    'area'=>$area, 
    'locality'=>$locality, 
        'doctor_id' => $this->session->userdata('some_name')
    );
 $this->load->model('ApiModel');
 $this->ApiModel->clinic_insert($add_image); 
}
```

you need to use $this->session->**userdata**("some_name); to get already set session.
$this->session->**set_userdata**("some_name", "value"); to set the value to session

Comment: i alredy set session  in another function.$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', $authUser['id']);

Comment: Y are you using like this  'doctor_id' =>$this->session->set_userdata('some_name') in array , you have added in commnet , it should be 'doctor_id' => $this->session->userdata('some_name') right?

Comment: sorry that was my fault

Comment: should i need to add session variable name in $config['auth_source']